# omitted relative pronoun - movie star we would like to be

Tags: relative-pronouns

In the following sentence, a relative pronoun is omitted.

> Few of us can become the professional athlete, entertainer, or movie star we would like to be.

Can you tell me what relative pronoun is omitted? Can "that", "which", and "who" be used as a relative pronoun here?

Comment: "That" is preferred over a _wh_ pronoun when the relative word is not subject, as in your example.

Answer (score 1):

"That" and "who" would be appropriate. "That" is a fairly general relative pronoun and can be used in most cases. "Who" refers to a person (or generally living thing. You wouldn't say "The dog, which..."). "Which" as a relative pronoun refers to an inanimate object.